# How to destroy/kill a service?

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have my application running a service for shake detect, however in my MainActivity, I have button for log out user, in which I must log out and terminate the service that detects the shake event.

my method for log out in my MainActivity is:

```
public void signOutAndFinish(){
    //Stop Shakeservice
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShakeService.class);
    stopService(intent);
    //Go to login activity
    Intent iLoginView = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(iLoginView);
}
```

however if I shake my device after logging out, the service recognizes the shake, it is as if it will not kill it immediately:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShakeService.class);
stopService(intent);
```

The code in the method onDestroy is:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

**How can I terminate the service so that when I log out the service dies?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a broadcast back your activity in the `onDestroy()` method of your service and then do the logout.

Here is some sample code of the above idea:

This for your service:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.example.broadcast.MY_NOTIFICATION");
    intent.putExtra("data","Notice for logout!");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

And this is for your activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver br = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.broadcast.MY_NOTIFICATION");
  registerReceiver(br, filter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  unregisterReceiver(br);
}

// An inner class at your activity
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        YourActivity.this.finish();
        // or do anything you require to finish the logout...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> however if I shake my device after logging out, the service recognizes the shake

Then presumably you did not clean up your `Sensor` stuff in the service's `onDestroy()` method.

> How can I terminate the service so that when I log out the service dies?

You are doing that now. However, if you set up something in the service, such as listening to events from `SensorManager`, you need to clean that up, typically in `onDestroy()` of the service.